# How can I get generic type of PsiField

Tags: generics, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm developing a Intellij Idea plugin,I want to get all fields info of a class.But I meet with difficulties which I can not get generic type of PsiField. Such as:

```
private String[] stringsArr;
private List<String> stringList;
private List<BeanLog> beanLogList;
```

How to get the PsiClass of 'BeanLog' from PsiField ?

Answer (score 11):

`field.getType()` returns PsiClassType `List<BeanLog>`. Its `fieldType.getParameters()[0]` will be PsiClassType `BeanLog`. If you want to extract a collection component type in a generic way (not only from `List`), then you can use `PsiUtil.extractIterableTypeParameter(fieldType, false)`. To get `PsiClass` from `PsiClassType`, you can use `type.resolve()` or `PsiUtil.resolveClassInClassTypeOnly`.

Comment: You give me a big favor!